# How to grant access for azure app API access to SharePoint onilne (office.com)

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, permissions, token, sharepoint-online

I need access to sharepoint online via API for azure app. I use OAuth for this purpose. On portal.azure.com I was register the app and added permissions for SHP (read/write).
My web service is able to get correct app token and call SHP API, but with `"401 - unauthorized"`.
I got correct answer from SHP API If user token was used - obtained from postman tool.
So I think, problem is on SHP rights settings. I tried add permission on `https://<sharepoint>/layouts/15/appinv.aspx`, but access is still not granted  after adding permission by this page.

So, I make something wrong. But what?
Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint app only permission can be set in this url:

https:// Tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

[image]

Reference:

[Connect To SharePoint Online Site With App Only Authentication](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connect-to-sharepoint-online-site-with-app-only-authentication/)

Here is guide to Granting access via Azure AD App-Only permission:

[Granting access via Azure AD App-Only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this way. But still don't know what should I exactly fill to the App Domain, Redirect URL and Scope (on permisson XML) and how these values ​​will affect the API call.

Comment: @MarekPřikryl, you can refer the following official document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint

It explained the scope URI and description with details